# Underscore.js flatten object keys to array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Supposing I have such object:

```
var obj = {
  'a': 'fizzle',
  'b': 'wizzle',
  'c': 'bum',
  'd': 'crum'
}
```

I would like to take the key names and flatten these into an array, like so:

```
// -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

I could achieve this with a simple object loop, however I am wondering if there is a common `underscore` utility that could turn it into a one-liner. I looked through the `underscore` functions and couldn't find one for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `Object.keys()` method available on the native `Object constructor` , Which outputs the original objects own enumerable properties.

```
Object.keys(obj);
```

Comment: Damn, 7 years of web dev and somehow I've never seen that before. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @dc2 . Sure no worries.. It happens with everyone once in a while :)